# how to Query all messages in a specific channel ? getstream.io

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

i would like to recover all the messages from a specific channel. From the docs, I was only able to find channel pagination and filter for a sepcific message but im looking for a query that provides something like this `client.queryMessages(podId: 7)`

Comment: Any update on this?